# JAVA Exception while using printf along with format specifier for int. Exception occurred in PrintStream as posted below

Tags: java

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("The value of integer is: %d",i);
        }
      }
}
```

Below is the output post execution

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)
at Application.main(Application.java:6)
```

Comment: Thank You. Changing the "Compiler compliance level" helped the cause.